# How get category_id by name in cs cart via API?

Tags: cs-cart

I can not find this in documentation.

Inside this function `fn_get_categories`, did not find.

Code from Api Categories:

`list($data, $params) = fn_get_categories($params, $lang_code);`

Answer (score 2):

You can find this `fn_get_categories` function from here `/var/www/html/app/functions/fn.catalog.php`.(behind the function)